# PHP session variable and javascript variable are asynchronous

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a captcha generator php script:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    header ("Content-type: image/png");

    /*irrelevant parts here*/

    $word = "";    
    for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
        $letter = $letters[rand(0, $len - 1)];         
        imagettftext($image, 15, 0, $i*50+25, 50, $text_color, $font, $letter);
        $word .= $letter;
    }
    $_SESSION['captcha_string'] = $word;        
    imagepng($image);
?>
```

I call it this way in my HTML/PHP page:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>

.. some irrelevant code here ..

<img id="captchaimg" src="captcha_generator.php">
```

And this is my javascript code which is **on the same HTML/PHP page** (I call this function with a button click):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function validCaptcha() {           
 var a = <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['captcha_string']); ?>;
 alert(a);
 }
</script>
```

My problem is that the javascript "is late", it gets the previous value of the session variable, not the actual. I think the reason is that when the page is loading the php runs AFTER the javascript did get the session variable. So, the javascript sees the previous session variable, while there is already a new one.
How can I get the ACTUAL session variable in the javascript function?

**UPDATE** to the question: when does the javascript function get the session variable? **When the page is loading or when the user clicks the button?**

Comment: _"I think the reason is that when the page is loading the php runs AFTER the javascript got the session variable"_ That's not possible. PHP gets processed on server side whereas Javascript is processed on client side. So, PHP will always be executed before JS.

Comment: OK, but what does cause the problem? The fact: javascript "is late".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found the solution. The key >> I had to make a **new php file** (called captchavalue.php in the example) which only has one task: echo the variable:

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    echo $_SESSION['captcha_string'];
?>
```

And here is the Ajax/Javascript (thanks for suggestion):

```
<script>
function validCaptcha() {
   var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
       document.getElementById("div_id").innerHTML = this.responseText;
      }
   };
   xhttp.open("GET", "includes/captchavalue.php", true);
   xhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

1.Here problem is the while loading page only **variable a= sessionvalue** assigned with session value.

2.Here you are creating captcha code after loading page and reassigning session value.

3.In php session value get updated.But in JS doesn't.

one alternative solution is send ajax call when you click on button and return session($_SESSION['captcha_string']) value from PHP. This could resolve your problem.

Comment: check this https://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_get

Comment: <script>
function validCaptcha() {

 
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      
      this.responseText;//what ever your returning from php you can catch here.
      
      
    }
  };
  
  xhttp.open("GET", "place your file/url which will return the session value from PHP", true);
  xhttp.send();
  
}
</script>